# Enabling BitLocker without TPM on MacBook Pro with Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have been wanting to enable BitLocker without a compatible TPM (my MacBook Pro) on a Bootcamp partition that has read / write access to the EFI. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to document this because the information that I've found is spread out and highly complicated. I've found a set of steps that are much simpler to enable BitLocker on a Bootcamp install of Windows. I've combined the information from these two sources for this guide:

- [How do I mount the EFI partition on Windows 8.1 so that it is readable and writeable?](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write)
- [Bitlocker in Windows 8.1 inside Bootcamp on the MacBook Pro (mid 2009)](https://antirandom.com/2014/10/10/bitlocker-in-windows-8-1-inside-bootcamp-on-the-macbook-pro-mid-2009/)

The first step is to boot into your Windows partition, then log in, and open up an administrative command prompt.

Mount the UEFI partition to a drive letter:
    `mountvol b: /s`

Copy the Microsoft EFI binaries to the UEFI partition:
    `bcdboot c:\windows /s b: /f UEFI`

Unmount the UEFI partition:
    `mountvol b: /d`

Configure BitLocker to work without a TPM:

1. Start => run => `gpedit.msc`
2. Open the Local Computer Policy node
3. Navigate to `Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows
   Components \ Bit Locker Drive Encryption \ Operating System Drives`
4. Double click on `Require additional authentication at startup`
5. Enable the feature and check the box next to `Allow BitLocker without
   a compatible TPM`, click Apply and Ok, and close out of Local Group
   Policy Editor.

Reboot your machine back to Windows.

You can now enable BitLocker on the device using just a passphrase.

Comment: Could anybody share an update if this solution is still working after several months? I tried something similar a while back and it all broke down after an OS update. The additional BitLocker partition was the source of many problems.

Comment: I can confirm that I did this on my MacBook Pro 2017 after it came back from repairs successfully. I haven't tried on the very latest builds of Windows, but it works fine with the release build of Windows 1709 and MacOS 10.12.

It's also important to note that the approach above does not create an 'additional BitLocker partition'. It simply places the Microsoft EFI binaries into the existing Mac EFI partition so that the machine has the necessary binaries available to handle BitLocker at boot.

Comment: If you're using a newer Macbook Pro (2018) then read my answer below.

Comment: I have a 2018 macboo pro with bootcamp and Win 10 pro. The boot camp partition is 60GB and 35GB are free. I followed the gpedit instructions noted above. I got an 0x8004259a error when try to activate bit locker. Any ideas?

Comment: @PeterBliss the error text is as follows: "The volume you have selected to shrink may be corrupted. Use Chkdsk to fix the corruption problem, and then try to shrink the volume again." Try running chkdsk

Comment: Error "Failure when attempting to copy boot files" is shown after typing: `bcdboot c:\windows /s b: /f UEFI` command. I followed previous steps before this. MacBook Pro 2016 15in, Windows 10Pro 64bit Bootcamp with macOS Catalina.

Comment: How can I follow your advice for Windows 7? Neither `/s` for `mountvol` nor `/f` for `bcdboot` switches are supported; it's unclear which partition holds UEFI. Without them, I seem to end up with a bricked Windows installation. I detailed my case in a [separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441459/bitlocker-on-bootcamp-windows-7-13-macbook-air-2011).

Comment: This process can work on a personal device, but any Mobile Device Management managed Device (MDM) will have its own set of requirements for encryption and will almost certainly not work.

Comment: @FoxDeploy - yes, you'll need to do this before MDM-joining your machine. Also note that this is only feasible on Intel Macs - Apple Silicon Macs don't support booting Windows natively.

Answer (score 4):

I had to encypt both Mac OS and Windows and wasn't sure about order, but found this article:

- https://medium.com/@vanister/encrypting-macos-and-windows-on-the-same-mac-842ee7a19c44

In short words:

1. First enable FileVault on Mac
2. Reboot in Windows
3. Disable TPM as described in other comments (using gpedit.msc)
4. Start Bitlocker encryption
5. Reboot Windows to finish the encryption (Bitlocker will prompt you to do so)

I tested this on MacBook Pro 13 2020 MacOS 10.15.7 and latest Windows 10.

Comment: In StatckExchange sites we like an answer to be useful even if the link is not reachable, ie precis the information in the answer. This is very important for places like medium whioch do not allow free access, they limit the number of articles you can read, so at the end of a month I will not be able to make any use of this answer

Comment: @mmmmmm I amended my answer. I thought only premium articles are limited on medium.

Comment: Good clarification, I should have that as the assumption. However, I don't believe that it matters whether FileVault is enabled on it or not if you're using APFS.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a newer Macbook Pro (i'm using the 2018 model) then it's pretty easy actually. I'd really recommend you to read these two guides and then you'll be up and running with Bitlocker in like less than 15 minutes:

- (Good description and overview) https://tonyho.net/filevault-and-bitlocker-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp/
- (Actual guide) https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/

I'm writing this from inside Windows 10 on my newly encrypted Bitlocker drive running Bootcamp on a Macbook Pro 2018.

Comment: Do you no longer need to copy the EFI binaries over with the 2018 models? What setting did you use in the Apple Secure Boot Utility?

Comment: No I did not need to copy binaries manually. What do you mean with Apple Secure Boot Utility? @kop48

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to try on my 2018 model and see how it goes.

The new MacBooks have the Secure Enclave processor that validates the secure boot chain of the machine. You can relax that validation using the utility: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330

Comment: I get this error "Bitlocker could not be enabled"  "The data drive specified is not specified to automatically unlock on the current computer and cannot be unlocked automatically. C: was not encrypted" this error following restart after following the steps that your links link to themselves https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/ Initial thoughts: what is the "data drive" that the error is referring to and where is the setting to "automatically unlock"

Comment: My issue documented further here: https://superuser.com/questions/1587124/which-drive-is-the-data-drive-referred-to-in-the-bitlocker-error-the-data-dri

Answer (score 1):

Adding some instructions on how to do this so that it works with Parallels too.

1. Follow all of the instructions [above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292900/179600) while booted into Windows
   natively with Bootcamp, but DON'T ENABLE BITLOCKER YET.
2. Next, go back to MacOS, fire up Parallels and create the VM from the
   Bootcamp partition.
3. Once you've done that, enable Bitlocker from within the VM in
   Parallels, set it to start with a password.

Voila! You'll now be able to unlock Bitlocker with a password either from Parallels, or booting natively with Bootcamp.

Answer (score -1):

**Successful solution, overcoming error**

I followed these steps for my MacBook Pro 15inch 2016 (touchbar) and was then able to over come the error I got as I've also described in the third step:

1. [How-To Geek: How to Use BitLocker Without a Trusted Platform Module
   (TPM)](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/)
2. [How-To Geek: How to Set Up BitLocker Encryption on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/192894/how-to-set-up-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows/)
3. [Which drive is the “data drive” referred to in the Bitlocker error
   “The data drive specified” where would it be set to “automatically
   unlock”?](https://superuser.com/questions/1587124/which-drive-is-the-data-drive-referred-to-in-the-bitlocker-error-the-data-dri/1587140#1587140) (solution to overcome error: "the data drive specified is not set to automatically unlock on the current computer and cannot be unlocked automatically" and "C: was not encrypted").

Comment: In StatckExchange sites we like an answer to be useful even if the link is not reachable, ie precis the information in the answer.