# Will encrypting the Windows partition with BitLocker wipe out the macOS partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, encryption, filevault

I am running macOS and Windows on a macbook pro using bootcamp.

I have encrypted my macOS partition using FileVault.

I have read, that BitLocker on Windows on Mac would wipe the macOS partition. Is there any truth to that?

What is the best way to also encrypt the Windows partition?

I am running macOS sierra.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, via BootCamp, BitLocker will only encrypt the Windows' system volume (drive C:). So MacOS will not be modified.

Of course, accessing your BitLocker encrypted volume when you are using your computer with MacOS is another matter. There are software doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a guide on enabling Bitlocker on your Bootcamp and/or Parallels partition here: [Enabling BitLocker without TPM on MacBook Pro with Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292899/enabling-bitlocker-without-tpm-on-macbook-pro-with-bootcamp/292900#292900)